# Legend of a RegionPlot of Lists

Tags: plotting

I have a list of regions I want to plot with RegionPlot, and a list of labels I want to use as their PlotLegends. Unfortunately passing to region plot the two lists does not work.

```
regions = {0.75` <= x <= 0.78`, 0.7` <= x <= 0.8`, 0.7` <= x <= 0.85`, 0.5` <= x <= 1.`};
labels = {"2", "4", "6", "8"};
RegionPlot[Reverse[regions], {x, 0.4, 1.2}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotLegends ->Reverse[labels]]
```

Returns the following output:
[image]

Where only the first Label is displayed, and not the other 3. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: `RegionPlot[Reverse[regions] // Evaluate, {x, 0.4, 1.2}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> Reverse[labels]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `// Evaluate` to the plotted region, or use the list itself in `RegionPlot[]`

```
regions = {0.75` <= x <= 0.78`, 0.7` <= x <= 0.8`, 0.7` <= x <= 0.85`,0.5` <= x <= 1.`};
labels = {"2", "4", "6", "8"};
RegionPlot[Reverse[regions] // Evaluate, {x, 0.4, 1.2}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> Reverse[labels]]
```

You may read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605635/detection-and-styling-of-multiple-functions-in-mathematicas-plot) to understand the reason.

[image]